# Animated polyline on google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Am new to google maps. I saw the second illustration on animated polylines you have posted on,

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/06/powerful-data-visualization-with.html

to be very intersting and what i exactly need for my institute's project tat is to show network traffic flow. Please post a sample code on how to accomplish the animation of arrows. help would be much appreciated

Thank you very much.

Comment: "please post code?" No, that's not how this site works!

Comment: sorry but i was really lost in here..i just wanted a start. :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Read this:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#PolylineSymbols

Comment: thank you...i couldnt come accross this cause i ddn know what to search..thanx again :)

Comment: Some links which can be helpful for you just check it once : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143864/multiple-google-map-polylines; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180727/animating-polylines-google-maps-v3#comment29022313_17180727 ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644427/multiple-polyline-to-a-marker-on-google-maps-api-v3 ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121506/stop-animation-symbol-on-polyline-googlemaps ;